# python win32wnet.WNetCancelConnection2 function

Tags: python

win32wnet.WNetCancelConnection2("",0,0)

What exactly I have to pass as the first parameter here ?

1. network path ?? eg:- "\\192.168.7.177"
2. machine_name 
   or something else .

Thanking everybody in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You were right regarding the network path. It should look something like this:

```
win32wnet.WNetCancelConnection2('\\\\127.0.0.1\\c$',0,0)
```

You can find out more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385427(v=vs.85).aspx

Don't forget about the escape character!